# How to find the port number for a remote server?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to set up SSH Python interpreter on Pycharm. In the wizard, it is askin for:

- Host
- Username
- Port

I know the the name of my remote workstation and my username. But where can I get the port number from? does it require settings of Pycharm on remote server? 
Instructions are not clear.

I have W10 on both sides.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Windows 10 remote server you have to enable/install an SSH server. Windows does have a native one, I saw that you can also use OpenSSH now.

And your SSH server should run on port 22 by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try default port 63342 of pycharm besides ssh connection port on 22 :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-debugger.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup an SSH server on your remote machine in order to connect to it.
See: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-to-connect-to-remote-server-linux-or-windows

Once you have done that, the host will be the address of the remote machine, the username and password will be the credentials of a user that exists on the remote machine and the port will be a number that you have chosen when you were setting up the SSH server (22 by default).